# Allow visitor to view an ad twice a day only using cookies

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have this script but it is not working well
I want to allow visitors to view ad twice a day via cookies
and show another ad on the third view

```
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$verifier = "verify";
$cookie_value = $IP;

setcookie($verifier, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$verifier])){

    echo "First view";
}
elseif(!isset($_COOKIE[$verifier])){
    echo "Second view";}

else {
    echo "Third view";
}
```

The result shows the first and the third view only

Comment: Your first view and second view conditions are the same, so for both a person's first and second view they'll get "First view".
Also why keep the cookie for a month if you're recording daily views?